# Вывести количество покупок для клиента

Tags: mysql

Требуется вывести имена клиентов с соотвествующими кол-вами покупок каждого. Т.е. нужно посчитать кол-во екземпляров sale для каждого client. Мой вопрос состоит как раз в написании этой команды.
[image: ER-модель]

Comment: *вывести имена клиентов с соотвествующими кол-вами покупок каждого* **или все же** *Т.е. нужно посчитать кол-во екземпляров sale для каждого client* **?**

Comment: В моем понимании это одно и то же. Результатом должна быть таблица с столбцами first_name, last_name, sale_number, вот так.

Comment: в первом случае запрос к 1 таблице, во 2-м запрос к нескольким

Comment: Обычный join, как будто хотите выбрать все sale с именами клиентов, вывод нужных полей и count(*) с group by client_id